# Moving settings.py out of django project, how to set up to make it in work correctly?

Tags: python, django

1 my project directory structure:

```
    ├── project_one
        ├── conf
        ├── dist
        ├── logs
        ├── backend_server
        ├── front_web
        ├── logs
        ├── uwsgi.sh
        └── venv3.5
```

2 `backend_server` is my Django project:

```
├── backend_server
    ├── app1
    ├── app2
    ├── manage.py
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── backend_server
    ├── templates
    └── utils
```

Now I want to move `backend_server.settings.py` into `conf` directory for convenience.

3 `conf/uwsgi.ini:`

```
chdir=/home/rookie/project_one/backend_server
module=backend_server.wsgi
enable-threads=True
...
http=0.0.0.0:port
```

4 `backend_server.wsgi.py`

```py
import os
import sys


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend_server.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

when i use `uwsgi` to start my project, it failed and i'm not sure how to correct this error.

can you help me about this?

Comment: Well if you've moved the settings, surely you need to change the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to point to where it is now?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you sir for feeding back, when i tried to join the path where conf is and settings, it raise `ImportError: No module named '/home/rookie/project_one/conf/settings'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the original code, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is a Python module path, not a file path. You need to ensure that the `conf` directory or its parent is on the pythonpath and refer to it via dotted notation.

So you could do for example:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/project_one/conf')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
```

Now that you've done this, you'll almost certainly need to change the ROOT_URLCONF setting to point to wherever the main urls.py is since it is not in the same place as the settings.

Note, this whole thing sounds like a mess, especially as the wsgi file is remaining in the backend_server directory. I'd think carefully about why you want to do it.